# Getting Code Coverage for functional Automation test using jacoco and sonar

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a project for which I have written functional test in another github repo. I need to get the code coverage report using jacoco. Its like the main project is in github repo `A` and test code is in github repo `B`. I am able to get jacocoIT.exec but when I process it with sonar it gives me no code coverage and also doesn't show any LOC details.

I am guessing since I am triggering test from repo `B` it is not able to get the details about classes for repo `A`.

Is there any way I can get code coverage for this kind of project ?

Comment: Did you try to run the JaCoCo report goals to check if there is any coverage?

Comment: Yes, i did that but there isn't any coverage. I am pretty sure the function test suite is covering most of the code.

Comment: So there is a mistake with your pom.xml or similar and not really related to SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look to a similar problem I solved using [SonarQube module](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner).

I explained how to set up with a [very similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37591322/2394026).