# SonarQube fails to get git blame information from Jenkins project

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.5

I configured a Jenkins Main Project `P` to manage two git repository `A` and `B`. This main project `P` only updates git sources and calls sonar analysis on sources from his workspace.

Here's my tree folder.

```
{Jenkins Install Path} \ workspace \ P 
                                     |-- A 
                                         |-- .git/
                                         |-- all projects A files
                                     |-- B
                                         |-- .git/
                                         |-- all projects B files
```

When Jenkins runs sonar analysis for `P`, I got the following error

```
SCM provider for this project is: git
2664 files to be analyzed
0/2664 files analyzed
Missing blame information for the following files:
(all files)
```

The error is logical because SonarQube is looking for a `.git` folder under `{Jenkins Install Path} \ workspace \ P`. It doesn't exist.

I looked around the internet to find a solution but I didn't find an answer. I am using SonarQube 5.5 installed on windows.

Do you have some idea to make SonarQube working with my configuration ?

This case is different than [Sonarqube: Missing blame information for the following files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432290) because the root cause is I am using two git folder fetch by a single SonarQube analysis.

**Sources I visited and read several times**

[SonarQube Git Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Git+Plugin)

[Seems similar but different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432290/sonarqube-missing-blame-information-for-the-following-files)

[Global SCM error in SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295261/how-can-i-use-git-as-the-scm-provider-in-sonarqube-5-0-using-sonar-runner/)

Comment: I think this is less a SonarQube (analysis) question than it is a Git (project structure) question. You might take a look at Git submodules

Comment: I understand your answer, but I don't want/ I can't change the structure of my git repository using submodules because modules `A` and `B` are separated git modules for years and `B` is a common modules used by several applications. I am afraid to not be able to use SCM in this configuration.

Comment: But you _could_ create a third repo that represents the actual project and do your checkouts inside it as sub-modules. Note that I haven't tested the blame function in this scenario, but theoretically it should work.

Comment: Maybe I can create a git repo under Jenkins workspace. I'll try something like that. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonarqube: Missing blame information for the following files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432290/sonarqube-missing-blame-information-for-the-following-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @CSchulz's answer I found the solution using [SonarQube module](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

I configured SonarQube to use two submodule corresponding to my `A` and `B` git projects. Each project get the name of git module as the important `projectBaseDir` parametre.

```
sonar.projectKey=P
sonar.projectName=P
sonar.projectVersion=4.0.0
sonar.binaries=.

sonar.cxx.includeDirectories=Common/Path
sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=cppCheckReport.xml # Reports are present in A and B forlder

#  2 modules definition
sonar.modules=A,B

# Module A
IHM.sonar.projectBaseDir=A
IHM.sonar.projectName=A
IHM.sonar.sources=.
IHM.sonar.cxx.includeDirectories=XXX

# Module B
Shares.sonar.projectBaseDir=B
Shares.sonar.projectName=B
Shares.sonar.sources=.
Shares.sonar.cxx.includeDirectories=XXX
```

I needed to figure out some configurations but it works and it is fine for me.

Comment: Unfortionally, this feature seems to be removed with Sonarqube 7.6 https://community.sonarsource.com/t/any-alternative-proposal-for-multi-module-analysis-properties-removed-in-sonarqube-7-6/7429

Answer (score 3):

You can setup an analysis job which is triggered by `P`.

The analysis job can take a parameter which repository inside of the workspace of `P` should be analysed. The job itself should use the same workspace as `P` and only call the SonarQube analysis.